# Custom git clean filter modifies file in commit but not working directory

Tags: git

I have a custom .gitattributes entry like so:

```
*.csproj text filter=csprojsort
```

The corresponding filter is set up like so in .git/config:

```
[filter "csprojsort"]
   clean = "path/to/repo/csprojsort.exe"
```

Upon commiting a .csproj file with changes, the filter executes as intended by sorting the file alphabetically and then proceeding to commit the changes. If I do a `git show path/to/file.csproj`, the changes show up.

However, the file does NOT change in my working directory, and git does not recognize that the current state is out of sync. Only when I checkout another branch and then checkout the original branch does the file update on disk.

Any clue what is behind this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like the filter is working as intended.  The documentation says a *clean* filter is "...used to convert the content of a worktree file to a blob upon checkin", which is exactly the behavior you're seeing.  It doesn't modify files in your working directory.

A *smudge* filter does the opposite: when you check out a file, the *smudge* filter runs before the data is written to a file.

Comment: Thanks, based on your comment I think I understand what clean is meant for (line endings and such). I will implement this sorting function in some other way,